# I am trying to make a logging framework in c++ but information is not being passed to the logger's subcomponents, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: c++, c++11, logging, mingw-w64

here is my code, when i try running this, main does output the information placed into the LoggerComponent, but not the Logger itself. I don't know why, what could be preventing the logger from passing information into the underlying loggercomponent?

i tried using information from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/
and from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/map-associative-containers-the-c-standard-template-library-stl/

logger.cpp:

```
#include "logger.hpp"

Logger::Logger(bool verbose, bool fileoutput)
{
    if(verbose)
    {
        LoggerComponent c1(LoggerLevel::DEBUG, &std::cout);
        addLogger (LoggerType::CONSOLE, &c1);
        c1.output (LoggerLevel::DEBUG, "This is the start of console output");
    }
    if(fileoutput)
    {

    }
}

void Logger::output(LoggerLevel level, std::string message)
{
    for(auto& x : components)
    {
        x.second->output (level, message);
    }
}

void Logger::addLogger(LoggerType type, LoggerComponent* component)
{
    if(components.find (type) == components.end ())
        components.emplace(type, component);
}

LoggerComponent* Logger::getLogger (LoggerType type)
{
    if(components.find (type) != components.end ())
        return components.at (type);
    return nullptr;
}

void Logger::clearLoggers()
{
    components.clear ();
}

void Logger::removeLogger(LoggerType type)
{
    if(components.find (type) != components.end ())
        components.erase (type);
}
```

logger.hpp

```
#ifndef LOGGER_HPP
#define LOGGER_HPP

#include "loggercomponent.hpp"

#include <map>

enum class LoggerType
{
    CONSOLE,
    FILE
};

class Logger
{
public:
    explicit Logger(bool verbose, bool fileoutput);

    void output(LoggerLevel level, std::string message);

    void addLogger(LoggerType type, LoggerComponent* component);
    void removeLogger(LoggerType type);
    void clearLoggers();
    LoggerComponent* getLogger(LoggerType type);

private:
    std::map<LoggerType, LoggerComponent*> components;
};

#endif // LOGGER_HPP
```

main.cpp

```
#include "logger.hpp"

int main()
{
    int* p;
    int i = 5;
    int j = 5;
    p = &i;
    std::cout << p << std::endl;
    p = &j;
    std::cout << p << std::endl;

    LoggerComponent c(LoggerLevel::DEBUG, &std::cout);

    c.output (LoggerLevel::INFO, "Hello World!");
    c.output (LoggerLevel::CRITICAL, "Hello World!");

    Logger c2(true, true);

    std::cout << c.getOutputStream () << std::endl;
    std::cout << c2.getLogger (LoggerType::CONSOLE)->getOutputStream () << std::endl;

    c2.output (LoggerLevel::INFO, "Hello World!");
    c2.output (LoggerLevel::CRITICAL, "Hello World!");
}
```

loggercomponent.hpp

```
#ifndef LOGGERCOMPONENT_HPP
#define LOGGERCOMPONENT_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

enum class LoggerLevel
{
    INFO,
    DEBUG,
    WARNING,
    ERROR,
    CRITICAL
};

class LoggerComponent
{
public:
    explicit LoggerComponent(LoggerLevel level, std::ostream* output);

    LoggerLevel getMinimumLevel();
    std::ostream* getOutputStream();
    void setMinimumLevel(LoggerLevel level);
    void setOutputStream(std::ostream* output);

    void output(LoggerLevel level, std::string outputMessage);

private:
    std::string getLevelString(LoggerLevel level);

    LoggerLevel minimumLevel;
    std::ostream* outputStream;
};

#endif // LOGGERCOMPONENT_HPP
```

loggercomponent.cpp

```
#include "loggercomponent.hpp"

LoggerComponent::LoggerComponent(LoggerLevel level,
                                 std::ostream* output)
{
    setMinimumLevel (level);
    setOutputStream (output);
}

void LoggerComponent::setMinimumLevel(LoggerLevel level)
{
    if(minimumLevel != level)
        minimumLevel = level;
}

void LoggerComponent::setOutputStream(std::ostream *output)
{
    if(outputStream != output)
        outputStream = output;
}

LoggerLevel LoggerComponent::getMinimumLevel()
{
    return minimumLevel;
}

std::ostream* LoggerComponent::getOutputStream()
{
    return outputStream;
}

std::string LoggerComponent::getLevelString(LoggerLevel level)
{
    switch (level) {
    case LoggerLevel::INFO:
        return "INFO";
    case LoggerLevel::DEBUG:
        return "DEBUG";
    case LoggerLevel::WARNING:
        return "WARNING";
    case LoggerLevel::ERROR:
        return "ERROR";
    case LoggerLevel::CRITICAL:
        return "CRITICAL";
    }
    return nullptr;
}

void LoggerComponent::output(LoggerLevel level, std::string outputMessage)
{
    if(level >= minimumLevel)
    {
        time_t now = time(nullptr);
        *outputStream << ctime(&now)
                      << (getLevelString (level) + " >> " + outputMessage)
                      << std::endl << std::endl;
    }
}
```

output:

0x60fda8
0x60fdac
Tue Oct 01 12:29:14 2019
CRITICAL >> Hello World!

Tue Oct 01 12:29:14 2019
DEBUG >> This is the start of console output

0x6fd0cd00
0x60fdb0

Comment: 1) Please provide [mcve] (what's `LoggerComponent`?). 2) Please provide expected output, and actual output, that you get. 3) Minor note: consider not using _cplusplus.com_. Use [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) instead.

Comment: here is the code for the logger component

Comment: @ShadowLynch you have reached complete, but overshot minimal by a large margin. What you really want to do is back up the code and then, bit by bit, remove everything that is NOT needed to reproduce the bug while still compiling and inserting no new bugs. This can be difficult to do, especially when you don't know where the bug is, but it almost always finds the bug, eliminating the need for asking a question. Isolating a bug is the best way to make sure you only have one bug and prove that a proposed fix actually does fix that one bug.

Comment: And niggly note: One of the tutorials is using the term STL (Standard Template Library) where it means to use Standard Library containers library. The STL heavily influenced the first C++ Standard and it still casts a long ideological shadow, but the two have diverged. STL is easier to type and is often used interchangeably, but it means something different, and sometimes the difference matters.

Comment: As a note, I wouldn't use UPPERCASE for none macro names, especially these common names are likely to conflict, with macros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are storing a pointer to an object local to the constructor (`c1`) in `components`. It will be destroyed and the pointer invalid when you try to use it later.

Store the object itself (or a `std::unique_ptr` to it if you have a good reason not to store the object itself) in the map instead.

Comment: thank you, ended up storing the data in the map using new, and thereby preventing the lvalue's deletion

Comment: @ShadowLynch No, that is precisely not what you should do. Change the type of `components` to `std::map<LoggerType, LoggerComponent>` and then `emplace` the `LoggerComponent` itself (which will make a copy of it).

Comment: OH! sorry, thought you meant the memory address so i used a pointer after calling a new instance of it

Comment: i tried what you said and came up with an error, no default constructor exists for LoggerComponent, I also tried using pointers toward a dynamically constructed place in memory and it worked

Comment: @ShadowLynch You should always be careful with `new`. It will cause memory management problems down the line. There is rarely a reason to use it. You should also pass-by-reference instead of pass-by-pointer most of the time.

Comment: the issue seems to happen in the tuple include file from my map file, which is calling a default constructor that doesn't exist, instead of the copy constructor

Comment: nvm, got it to work, my copy function was using the operator[] instead of at, which was reinstantizing the loggercomponent with 0 constructor args

Comment: @ShadowLynch Yes, if you save the `LoggerComponent` directly in the map and don't want to give it a default constructor, then you need to use `find`/`at` and `emplace`/`insert`/`insert_or_assign`/`try_emplace` instead of `operator[]`. But that isn't a good reason not to save the object directly in the map, because if you had stored a pointer instead, `operator[]` may have inserted a null-pointer when the key wasn't found and that is something that you surely don't want to happen.

Comment: oh, didn't know that last part, makes sense now! Thank you a ton!